# Delete Multiple keysets in Maps using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object, maps

Hi I have a map consisting of key-value pairs. How do i remove multiple keysets in my map ?

Map creation part

```
  // result key something like 0-119,0-110,0-118 for each entries
  this.OptionsMap.set(''+result, selectedList[index]);
```

Map Deletion Part

```
 Const entriesd = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selectedList));
     for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(entriesd)) 
            {
                 if (value.key === 'AB')
                {
                  console.log('keys',value.index)
                 this.OptionsMap.delete(''+value.index);
                  
                }
               
            }
```

selectedList

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: "101", value: "A1B", key: "AB", index: "0-119", …}
1: {id: "130", value: "130", key: "AB", index: "0-110", …}
2: {id: "130", value: "130", key: "AB", index: "0-118", …}
```

Now in console.log i could get my index like 0-119,0-110,0-118 but in delete part how to remove multiple index? please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: selectedList is actually an Array and you want to filter it excluding entries where key property is   'AB' ... or you want to do anything else?

Comment: @Reflective yeah this.OptionsMap those map value i want to delete the OptionMap value using selectedList . Basically i want to clear the OptionMap whatever the console is printed.please help me sir

Comment: what is the type of `this.OptionsMap`? Typed array or something else?

Comment: @Reflective its a map  OptionsMap = New Map();

Comment: Also please suggest some easy way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not wrong, your code seems to work ... but you want easiest way?

Comment: No actually its deleting only single value not entire one.

Answer (score 0):

What about that?

```js
// SETTING AN EXAMPLE FOR THE CASE
var selected = [
  {id: "101", value: "A1B", key: "AA", index: "0-119"},
  {id: "130", value: "130", key: "AB", index: "0-110"},
  {id: "130", value: "130", key: "AB", index: "0-118"}
];
var optionsMap = new Map([
  ["0-119", {id: "101", value: "A1B", key: "AA", index: "0-119"}],
  ["0-110", {id: "130", value: "130", key: "AB", index: "0-110"}],
  ["0-118", {id: "130", value: "130", key: "AB", index: "0-118"}],
  ["0-117", {id: "135", value: "131", key: "AB", index: "0-117"}],
  ["0-116", {id: "136", value: "132", key: "AB", index: "0-116"}],

]);
console.log('optionsMap.size',optionsMap.size);

// ACTUAL FILTERING
// THIS WILL DELETE ONLY THE OPTIONS BEING SPECIFIED IN selected
// AND HAVING KEY 'AB'

selected.filter(item => item.key === 'AB').forEach(el => optionsMap.delete(el.index));

// RESULT
console.log('optionsMap.size',optionsMap.size);
```